# dotnet core azure documentdb linq lambda query not running query on server

Tags: performance, linq, .net-core, azure-cosmosdb

I'm running dotnet core and accessing documentdb.

When I try to run a query using a linq where clause it returns but it takes a long time and doesn't seem to filter on the server. I was able to resolve this by using the SqlQuerySpec to run the query and it now appears to run the query criteria on the server.

Is this a known issue or am I missing something?

**The one that doesn't work:**

```
var query = _client.CreateDocumentQuery<T>(documentCollection.DocumentsLink).Where(criteria);    
return query.ToList();
```

criteria is of type

```
Func<T, bool> criteria
```

**The one that does work:**

```
var documentQuery = _client.CreateDocumentQuery<T>(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(_databaseName, collectionName), query).AsDocumentQuery();
List<T> results = new List<T>();
while (documentQuery.HasMoreResults)
{
results.AddRange(await documentQuery.ExecuteNextAsync<T>());
}
return results;
```

query is of type

```
SqlQuerySpec query
```

Is this a feature that is lagging behind in dotnet core's implementation of the documentdb sdk vs the standard .NET package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are using `Func<T, bool>` for criteria. The one that you're using is for `IEnumerable`. By design `IEnumerable` will do in-memory filtering (client-side).

`CreateDocumentQuery.Where()` actually returns an `IQueryable`. You need to change your criteria type to `Expression<Func<T, bool>>`as this is what is expected by `CreateDocumentQuery`.

When you use an `Expression`, your LINQ expression is converted to the database specific SQL query and will be executed on the server.

```
Uri documentCollectionUri = UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(DatabaseId, CollectionId);
var query = client.CreateDocumentQuery<T>(documentCollectionUri)
                  .Where(predicate)
                  .AsDocumentQuery();
List<T> results = new List<T>();
while (documentQuery.HasMoreResults)
{
    results.AddRange(await documentQuery.ExecuteNextAsync<T>());
}

return results;
```

Where `predicate` is `Expression<Func<T, bool>>`

One important thing to remember: You can only use those LINQ extentions that have an equivalent function in the DocumentDb's SQL language. For example, you can use `Take()` but you cannot use `Skip()`, you cannot use Array contains on specific nested fields, etc.

Answer (score 0):

> When I try to run a query using a linq where clause it returns but it takes a long time and doesn't seem to filter on the server.

If we capture the request when run `var query = _client.CreateDocumentQuery<T>(documentCollection.DocumentsLink).Where(criteria);`, we could find it [performs a GET on the documents resource of a particular collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/documentdb/list-documents)

`GET https://{databaseaccount}.documents.azure.com/dbs/{db-id}/colls/{coll-id}/docs` to get a list of documents under the collection, which does not really [query and filter on DocumentDB server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/documentdb/query-documents).

And [Where method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535040(v=vs.110).aspx) is used to filter a sequence of values based on a predicate, which happens on the client (not pass the search condition to DocumentDB server).